# rtt-exercise building error-orocos-toolchain

Tags: ros, real-time

I am using ros kinetic in ubuntu 16.04. My first error is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/ros/kinetic/share/ros/core/rosbuild/bin/check_same_directories.py", line 46, in <module>
    raise Exception
Exception

    CMake Error at /opt/ros/kinetic/share/ros/core/rosbuild/private.cmake:102 (message):
  [rosbuild] rospack found package "controller-1" at "", but the current
  directory is "/home/robot/rtt-exercises-2.7.0/controller-1".  You should
  double-check your ROS_PACKAGE_PATH to ensure that packages are found in the
  correct precedence order.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /opt/ros/kinetic/share/ros/core/rosbuild/public.cmake:177 (_rosbuild_check_package_location)
  CMakeLists.txt:24 (rosbuild_init)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/home/robot/rtt-exercises-2.7.0/controller-1/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
```

So when i enter command " export ROS_PACKAGE_PATH=${ROS_PACKAGE_PATH}:~/rtt-example/rtt_examples-rtt-2.0-examples/rtt-exercises/controller-1 " than i'm getting below error:

```
Failed to invoke /opt/ros/kinetic/bin/rospack deps-manifests controller-1
[rospack] Error: package 'controller-1' depends on non-existent package 'rtt' and rosdep claims that it is not a system dependency. Check the ROS_PACKAGE_PATH or try calling 'rosdep update'


CMake Error at /opt/ros/kinetic/share/ros/core/rosbuild/public.cmake:129 (message):


  Failed to invoke rospack to get compile flags for package 'controller-1'.

  Look above for errors from rospack itself.  Aborting.  Please fix the
  broken dependency!

Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /opt/ros/kinetic/share/ros/core/rosbuild/public.cmake:207 (rosbuild_invoke_rospack)
  CMakeLists.txt:24 (rosbuild_init)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/home/robot/rtt-exercises-2.7.0/controller-1/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log"
```

I have already installed the rtt-ros-integration package and orocos-toolchain package from source. And when i enter command " source ~/ws/underlay_isolated/installd_isolated/setup.sh " it again repeates the first error. So how should i solve this error. I was practicing the rtt-example package tutorial to learn orocos basics. This package is also avialabe in [[here](https://people.mech.kuleuven.be/~orocos/pub/stable/examples/rtt/tutorial/):]

Comment: the link at the very end of your post is invalid .... `controller-1` is an odd package name ... are you sure that it is a package?

Comment: this is the real link : https://people.mech.kuleuven.be/~orocos/pub/stable/examples/rtt/tutorial/

Comment: but when i try to build the link i mentioned at first also the same error came. and i am using package version 2.7 as that was the last one, even if i have istalled orocos-toolchian version 2.9 in my system. i have build and usedd all the hello world packages.